# There are 2 tables, A(column a) and B(column b). I want to find the number of occurrences of each value in table A column a in table B column b

Tags: sql-server

There are 2 tables, A(column 'a') and B(column 'b'). I want to find the number of occurrences of each value in table A  column 'a' in table B column 'b'.

Currently, I am using a brute force approach, and it is way too slow. What could be better ways of approaching this problem?

Example: 
[image]

Output 
[image]

Brute-force Approach:

```
WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @ValSpaceMod VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @ModSpaceValSpaceMod VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @ModSpaceVal VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @cnt integer;

    SELECT TOP 1 @Val = a FROM A

    SET @ValSpaceMod = @Val + ' %';
    SET @ModSpaceVal = '% ' + @Val;
    SET @ModSpaceValSpaceMod = '% ' + @Val + ' %';

    SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM B 
    WHERE ( LOWER(B.b) LIKE lower(@Val) 
       OR   LOWER(B.b) LIKE lower(@ValSpaceMod)
       OR   LOWER(B.b) LIKE LOWER(@ModSpaceValSpaceMod)
       OR   LOWER(B.b) LIKE LOWER(@ModSpaceVal)
          )

    PRINT @Val + ' ' + CAST(@cnt AS VARCHAR)

    DELETE A WHERE a= @Val
END
```

Comment: Consider using [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. The result is not exactly equal to your expected output, but that is because I considered that the fourth row on table B should increment the A count. If that is not right, please let me know so I can adjust the script.

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#tbT1') is not null
drop table #tbT1
GO

if object_id ('tempdb..#tbT2') is not null
drop table #tbT2
GO

create table #tbT1 (
    v char(1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)

create table #tbT2 (
    t varchar(255) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)

insert into #tbT1
values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')

insert into #tbT2
values ('A first value B second value'),
    ('B second value D fourth value'),
    ('D fourth value'),
    ('C third value Afirst')


select t1.v, sum (
    len(t2.t) - len(replace(t2.t, ' ' + t1.v + ' ', '  ')) -- middle occurrences
  + case when t2.t like t1.v + ' %' then 1 else 0 end -- add starting occurence
  + case when t2.t like '% ' + t1.v then 1 else 0 end -- add ending occurence
  ) as nOccurencies
from #tbT1 t1, #tbT2 t2
group by t1.v
```

Comment: The count of the search term should only be incremented when the search term matches completely, and is not a substring of another word.

Ex - A count will increase in cases when string is "**A** fine day", "What **a** catch!", "Incomplete **A**"

It should not increase in such cases: "Wh_a_t", "_A_dd"

Comment: I have updated the script to do a case insensitive compare and to ignore the substring of another word cases.

Comment: the adjustments I made won't work... let me work on that... give me a few min

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query (to get the number of occurrences of each value in table A column 'a' in table B column 'b' using the keyword `like`)

```
SELECT  [A].a AS SearchTerm
        ,(  SELECT  count(*)
            FROM    [B]
            WHERE   b LIKE '%'+[A].a+' %'
            COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS )  AS  Occurrences
FROM    [A]
```